# Converting JOGL texture into BufferedImage

Tags: java, textures, bufferedimage, jogl, fbo

I am very very new to JOGL. I am trying to create a BufferedImage object(which is used in other part of my code) out of a textrure (not a Texture object but a texture with a handle, storage). In the internet so far my searches gave me results to get a trexture from BufferImage but not the other way around which is my problem.

Is there a way to do this ?? by the way the texture is generated by a Frame buffer object to which I do a off screen rendering.

I create my texture in a very stright forward way with the following steps:
bindTexture
Setup the properties of textrure
Generate it from the data
unbind the texture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use glReadPixels to read the FBO pixels into a byteBuffer

the answer from here does that and returns a bufferedimage: [ReadPixel in Jogl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4173420/readpixel-in-jogl)

Comment: Thank you. I saw that some days back. It worked but it proved to be very expensive for me as my screen changes very rapidly. Thank you again.. !